# Can't calculate correct difference between two timestamps

Tags: php, wordpress, variables, time, comparison

I am creating a WordPress plugin, and what I want it to do is store a UNIX timestamp in the database and then update the DB entry if an hour or more has elapsed.

Here is a code snippet from my plugin:

```
const DB_TIME = 'my_database_key';

$db_option_time = get_option ( DB_TIME );
$now = time();

switch ( $db_option_time ) {

case false:
    update_option ( DB_TIME, $now );

    break;

case true:
    $time_difference = $now - $db_option_time;

    if ( $time_difference >= 3600 ) {
        update_option ( DB_TIME, $now );
    }

    break;

default:

    break;

}
```

If I run `var_dump()` on the `$db_option_time` and `$now` variables it shows me two different timestamps, except the `$db_option_time` timestamp is different to what's saved in the database!

On checking the timestamp in the database against the `$now` variable, there is a difference greater than 3600 seconds (when checking with my trusty calculator). I think something is going wrong with the `get_option` WordPress function?

Here's an example:

- Database entry (checked in phpMyAdmin) is **1367324833**
- The `get_option()` WordPress function returns **1367330177** (as shown from `var_dump()` on the `$db_option_time` variable)

It seems that `get_option()` function is pulling the correct timestamp from the database and then doing something to it?

Comment: just do a debug - print `$now`, print `$db_option_time`, print `$time_difference`...

Comment: I just updated my original post. `$now` is correct, but the problem seems to be the `get_option()` function changing the value read in from the DB as it's being saved in to my `$db_option_time` variable.

Comment: `get_option()` of db_time should be doing an update and fetch in order to get the latest DB_TIME

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be using a switch for this type of functionality. If the `my_database_key` is not in the database, it will return `false` but otherwise it will return a number which does not equal `true`. It is greatly simplified using and `if` statement since your logic is largely around when to set a new value to the database.

In the example below...

- set the option key
- set `$now` to the current time
- check to see if the `$db_option_time` value is absolutely `false`, *or* if there is greater than or equal to 3600 seconds between it and `$now`.
- if yes, set the option key `my_database_key` to `$now`

Code:

```
const DB_TIME = 'my_database_key';
$now = time();
$db_option_time = get_option ( DB_TIME );
if ( false === $db_option_time || $now - $db_option_time >= 3600 ){
    update_option ( DB_TIME, $now );
}
```